# Access detail view of UISplitViewController on iPhone

Tags: ios, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app I'm using a `UISplitViewController`. I wrote the code below to show a restaurant in the detail view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRestaurant:(Restaurant *)restaurant {
    UINavigationController *nvc = [[self.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    RestaurantsTabViewController *rtc = [[nvc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [rtc addTabWithRestaurant:restaurant];
}
```

This works fine on iPad, since it's rendering both the master and detail view. On iPhone it crashes on this line `UINavigationController *nvc = [[self.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];` though, because the detail view hasn't been rendered yet. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the Swift solution but I am pretty sure that you can adapt the code to your Objective-C environment. :)

Simply add a check to make sure that your `rtc` is not `nil`. If it is `nil` create a new instance and call the `UISplitViewController`s `showDetailViewController:sender:` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRestaurant restaurant: Restaurant) {
    if let detailNavigationController = splitViewController?.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController,
        let rtc = detailNavigationController.viewControllers.first as? RestaurantsTabViewController {
        rtc.addTabWithRestaurant(restaurant)
    } else {
        let rtc = RestaurantsTabViewController()
        rtc.addTabWithRestaurant(restaurant)
        splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(rtc, sender: self)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE - Objective-C solution could look something like this:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRestaurant:(Restaurant *)restaurant {
    if (self.splitViewController.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        UINavigationController *nvc = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        RestaurantsTabViewController *rtc = [nvc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        [rtc addTabWithRestaurant:restaurant];
    } else {
        RestaurantsTabViewController *rtc = [RestaurantsTabViewController new];
        [rtc addTabWithRestaurant:restaurant];
        [self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:rtc sender:self];
    }
}
```